# How to show next/prev links for specific category

Tags: next-prev

I have an artists page where i want to show next/prev from that artist
How to do that in Expression Engine?
Also: The artist is a child of a parent, and i only want the child(artist id) not parent category id. The {exp:channel:next_entry/prev_entry} tag is outside of my   {exp:channel:entries} tag

This works:

```
                {exp:channel:next_entry category="12" }
                     <a href="{path='portfolio/project'}">Next Project</a>
                {/exp:channel:next_entry}

                {exp:channel:prev_entry category="12" }
                     <a href="{path='portfolio/project'}">Previous Project</a>
                {/exp:channel:prev_entry}
```

And this gives 12 as result because of some previous coding:

```
                  <? echo $artistid ?>
```

So i thought this would work:

```
                {exp:channel:next_entry category="<?php echo $artistid ?>" }
                       <a href="{path='portfolio/project'}">Next Project</a>
                {/exp:channel:next_entry}

                {exp:channel:prev_entry category="<?php echo $artistid ?>" }
                     <a href="{path='portfolio/project'}">Previous Project</a>
                {/exp:channel:prev_entry}
```

Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a parse order issue:
http://loweblog.com/downloads/ee-parse-order.pdf

You can use an embed or probably also [**Stash**](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/stash). I can't tell you how with Stash but here's how with an embed:

---

In main template, change the next/previous code to:

```
{embed="includes/prevnext" id="<?php echo $artistid ?>"}
```

> *** update "includes/prevnext" to your actual template name.

---

Then in the "includes/prevnext" template, use:

```
 {exp:channel:next_entry category="{embed:id}" }
   <a href="{path='portfolio/project'}">Next Project</a>
 {/exp:channel:next_entry}

 {exp:channel:prev_entry category="{embed:id}" }
   <a href="{path='portfolio/project'}">Previous Project</a>
 {/exp:channel:prev_entry}
```

Comment: perfect! for some reason i was thinking the embed wouldn't know the current entry id, but it does